# Error when setting multiple ActiveMQ brokers in same machine

Tags: java, linux, activemq-classic, broker

I fallowed the exact steps in [1] in order to setup multiple ActiveMQ brokers in the same server. 
When I start the second instance I always get the same error.

One thing I noticed is configurations on both instances are same. for instance configurations like port s are same in both activemq.xml and jetty.xml.

I even change the ports of the second instance so it won't get crashed with the first intance. But I get the same Exception.

https://sbforge.org/display/BITMAG/Running+multiple+activemq+instances+on+the+same+server

INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 (instance1, ID:udara-54224-1391513355578-0:1) is shutdown
 INFO | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@33e228bc: startup date [Tue Feb 04 06:29:14 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
 WARN | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: **LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context:** org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@33e228bc: startup date [Tue Feb 04 06:29:14 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook.run(SpringContextHook.java:30)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:782)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.stop(XBeanBrokerService.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:574)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to those instructions, you definitely need to change the ports for each instance

```
each instance had its port numbers in <instance>/conf/activemq.xml and conf/jetty.xml edited, so instance1 listens on port 60001 and is managed on port 8001, instance2 on 60002 and 8002, instance3 on 60003 and 8003
```

That stack trace that you printed is a WARN and not an ERROR - does it not still work anyway? The log you printed is for instance1 - are you trying to start instance2? In which case your config for instance2 is wrong. Do a file search in the instance2/conf/ folder for any references to instance1, that should hopefully show you where the error is